# React Native Release Crash, TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Ae[n]')

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, crashlytics

React Native app crash in some device

this crash sometimes happen, sometimes not

this is the error that report in Firebase Crashlytics

```
Fatal Exception: com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Ae[n]'), stack: <unknown>@2710:5354 forEach@-1 onScroll@2710:5329 scrollResponderHandleScroll@262:2519 scrollResponderHandleScroll@-1 _handleScroll@261:3393 f@93:184 v@93:327 y@93:381 k@93:676 Ce@93:13197 Y@93:5364 <unknown>@93:13545 xe@93:92675 Re@93:12995 ze@93:13384 receiveEvent@93:13794 value@44:3492 <unknown>@44:747 value@44:2538 value@44:719 value@-1
```

Can someone please tell me what this error is?

Thanks